# Display image from API in Vue

Tags: html, image-processing, vue.js, strapi

I am using Strapi as an API driven CMS. I uploaded an image on Strapi and am pulling it on my Vue app. Strapi is using Mongo. The API is returning this for the image:

```
{
   "related":[ "5sd8c393cc22cb0slf292c49"],
   "_id":"5ae2c295cc84cb0daa234d8e",
   "name":"imgName.jpg",
   "hash":"x34f780e5c678a7398d69b35e74f0c33",
   "ext":".jpg",
   "mime":"image/jpeg",
   "size":98.68,
   "url":"/uploads/b96g789e5c094a7398d84d94j74f0c96.jpg",
   "provider":"local",
   "createdAt":"2018-04-27T06:47:32.351Z",
   "updatedAt":"2018-04-27T06:47:32.356Z",
   "__v":0,
   "id":"5ae2c395bg54cb0ser292c4a"
}
```

How can I display this image on Vue?

Comment: check this [Images in HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Images_in_HTML) to learn how to show image in HTML

Comment: I tried plugging the url into the src. Doesn't work that easy.

Comment: Are you including the domain part in the url? Can you include the code where you plugged the url into the image source tag?

Comment: open that URL, then scroll down a little bit, you will find the instruction about how to put one correct source to `<img>`

Comment: Oh wow, I was using my web app port in the url instead of the APIs -__- thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried some code to pull this data into your Vue app yet?

Comment: Can you please explain how you corrected this issue?